# Coin-OR -- Extracting Gomory Cuts from Cgl (Coin-Or)

Tags: mathematical-optimization, solver, constraint-programming

I'm trying to extract Cgl Gomory cuts out of the [Cgl](https://projects.coin-or.org/Cgl) (Cut Generation Library) of [Coin-Or](http://www.coin-or.org/) The following is the code I'm using to extract the cuts -

```
OsiCuts cutlist;
CglGomory * gomory = new CglGomory();
gomory->setLimit(100);
gomory->generateCuts(*sym, cutlist) ;
```

where sym is an instance of OsiSymSolverInterface (the OsiSolverInterface for Symphony). Unfortunately the code is segfaulting at generateCuts somewhere inside the method as far as I've been able to determine using gdb.

Extraction of CglProbing cuts is likewise segfaulting again inside the generateCuts method of the CglProbing class.

All other cuts seem to be working fine.

If someone could shed some light on this or even better, post/link to an example file using these cuts or a tutorial of some sort, that would great. If there's an example/tutorial for extracting cuts out of some other solver like SCIP instead of Coin-OR, that would work too.

Thanks